# How to install kafka module in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have problem when import KafkaUtils is :
No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka' But i don't know how to install kafka module.

I use python 3.6.8, spark 2.2.0 and kafka_2.12-2.5.0

Comment: do you have strict requirement to use Spark Streaming? Why not to use Spark Structured Streaming: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html ?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, KafkaUtils is being deprecated and replaced with Spark Structured Streaming. Which means you have two paths forward:

1. Redesign your application to use Structured Streaming instead (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html for a primer).
2. Downgrade your version of Spark to a version that still includes KafkaUtils as part of the distribution (you'll find that KafkaUtils won't need to be installed separately).